# What is the best way to filter by date when the date is broken out as 2 integers, Month & Year?

Tags: datetime, ado.net, datatable, filter

I have a DataTable that has a date broken up by Month & Year.  I need to filter by date so I was thinking about adding a column with an expression to get a true DateTime column.  Is this the best way handle this?  Can 'Convert' do this?  Something like...

```
dt.Columns.Add("RealDate", typeof(DateTime), "Convert(Month + '/1/' + Year, 'System.DateTime')");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, I'll reiterate the code I used:

```
dt.Columns.Add("RealDate", typeof(DateTime), "Convert(Month + '/1/' + Year, 'System.DateTime')");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would perform the transformation in the SQL that populates the DataTable. That might be inline SQL, a stored procedure, or an ORM.

**Let the database engine do the work.** Don't spend a lot of resource performing these transformations and calculations in your app.

**Edit**: If you can't alter the process generating the DataTable, you can filter by using a DataView RowFilter, like this:

```
DataView dataView = dataTable1.DefaultView;
dataView.RowFilter = string.Format("Month = '{0}' && Year = '{1}'", Month, Year);
```

[Here's a terrific page of examples, with demos and code](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/data/DataViewClassRowFilter.aspx).

Comment: Yes, Homer, you can write the filter to include the day, and you can use greater than or greater than/equal to.

Comment: What I'm saying is: 1/1/2009 > 8/8/2008 is true, (1 > 8) AND (2009 > 2008) is false.  I need an actual date field here.  Anyway, the expression I put in the question details worked.